# What is the difference between PAYPAL REST and PAYPAL EXPRESS? - using Omnipay API

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, omnipay

What is the difference between PAYPAL REST and PAYPAL EXPRESS? - using Omnipay API

I want to integrate a Payment Gateway on my site, but i don't know the differences on integration steps between the both ways.

I need to verify if the payment was succesfull and the payment was the correct amount.

Can someone help me understand the differences between these integrations?

Answer (score 1):

Express may refer to the old classic NVP/SOAP SetExpressCheckout / DoExpressCheckoutPayment APIs.

REST may refer to any number of newer REST APIs, including the deprecated `v1/payments` and current `v2/checkout/orders` APIs.

As for which ones Omnipay has implemented, consult their documentation or support